# (ReactJS) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import products from '../products'


function RecScreen() {
  const [budget, setBudget] = useState(products);
  const [items, setParts] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setBudget(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await fetch(`/api/products?price=${budget}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    setParts(data.product);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>PC Parts Recommender</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Enter your budget:
          <input type="number" value={budget} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        </label>
        <button className='btn btn-warning rounded ms-1' type="submit">Recommend Parts</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {items.map(product => (
          <li key={product.id}>{product.name} - ${product.price}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RecScreen;
```

**React code**
In this code user enter budget and recommend pc parts but its show nothing and give this
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: What does the JSON response look like? If the response does not contain a `product` key, you're setting `items` to `undefined`.

Comment: What type do you see when you `console.log(typeof data.product)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here the prolem is that the property `product` does not exist in the object `data`, however you are updating your state `items` with `data.product` which is `undefined` so when you try to map through `items` using `items.map` you are trying to map through an `undefined` value

To handle this use this code instead :

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const response = await fetch(`/api/products?price=${budget}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data) // see what your data object looks like
  if(data?.product){ // make this condition to only update the state when data exist and data.product exists
    setParts(data.product);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If data.product has a falsy value then in that case it will throw this error,you can modify this function like this

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`/api/products?price=${budget}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setParts(data.product || []);
  };
```